# $tab output from bca in ade4

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, pca

I know it could be a stupid question, but anyone can explain me what the $tab output from `bca()` in ade4 package mean? I did:

```
> obs.pca=dudi.pca(data.frame(t(data)), scannf=F, nf=10)
> obs.bet=bca(obs.pca, fac=as.factor(data.cluster), scannf=F, nf=2)
```

I'd like to understand better the different outputs given by this command, most of all the $tab. On the ade4 manual is explained `a data frame class-variables containing the means per class for each variable. Anyone can explain me better what does it mean?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather, the analysis finds X classes, and this will give you the variable average for each variable V1 to Vp in those X classes.

For specific questions on the ade4 package, there is a really good mailing list. The messages are in French and English: adelist@listes.univ-lyon1.fr